# PHP does nothing when overriding a static method

Tags: php

Consider this:

```
class Player {

    public static function echoSomthing(){
        echo "A";
    }

}
```

And

```
class ModifiedPlayer extends Player {

        public static function echoSomthing(){
            echo "B";
        } 
}
```

Ok, so I override my static echoSomthing function, but "A" still get echoed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try invoking like this `ModifiedPlayer::echoSomthing();`

Comment: I get Only 'B'... I put these line below : $m = new ModifiedPlayer();
$m->echoSomthing();

Comment: @xFlare You can try this https://eval.in/822772

Comment: Ah well, this is for a plugin. I don't have access to the parent class. The parent class calls the echoSomthing function

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments of [Sahil Gulati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5423014/sahil-gulati) and [pAsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1730976/pash) and also other,

we need to access any static method with scope resolution operator `::`

Please run following code and it will output `B`

```
<?php
class Player {
    public static function echoSomthing() {
        echo "A";
    }
}
class ModifiedPlayer extends Player {
    public static function echoSomthing() {
        echo "B";
    }
}
ModifiedPlayer::echoSomthing();
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/So7X87g1)

Comment: Problem is, this is for a plugin. I don't have access to the parent class, I can only extend it. and the parent class calls the static function.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Player {

    public static function echoSomthing(){
        echo "A";
    }

}

class ModifiedPlayer extends Player {

    public static function echoSomthing(){
        echo "B";
    }
}    

$ob = new ModifiedPlayer();    
$ob->echoSomthing(); // B displayed here
```